# How do I setContentView on the basis of data fetched from the table in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the **attendance_sheet.xml** file where the number of check boxes is calculated by retrieving the number of students in the 'student_login' table. The name of the check box also should be from the table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="      XYZ" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="      PQR" />  



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bUpdateAttendance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit Attendance" />

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in **DbHelper.class**

```
private static final String STUDENT_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + STUDENT_TABLE + "( s_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            + "s_name TEXT NOT NULL , s_pass TEXT NOT NULL , "
            + "s_roll_no TEXT NOT NULL , " + "s_email TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

**TeacherloggedInPage.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attendancesheet);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                t_id = (String) null;

            } else {
                t_id = extras.getString("key");

            }
        } else {
            t_id = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("key");
        }

        UpdateAttendanceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdateAttendance);
        UpdateAttendanceButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you needs to do ,

1) Create checkbox dynamically.

2) On based on names from Database , give checkBox names.

3) add them into your Layout(May be LinearLayout)

Here is the similar answer [How to add CheckBoxes Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13226652/519718)

your Layout xml should be like below

```
<Linear Layout With orientation Vertical>
  <Linear Layout with Orientation Vertical /> // Add CheckBoxes in this Layout, By taking its ID in the code.
  <Update BUtton>
</Linear Layout closing for top LL>
```

Comment: do i have to remove this line from the code
setContentView(R.layout.attendancesheet);
or 
add the the code given on the link below this line?

Comment: You dont need to copy the code, First try to read student data from database. when you have them create CheckBoxes, like given in the link